# How do I add a vote count to reaction?

Tags: python, discord, discord.py

Hi I'm working on a music cog and I'm figuring  out how to do a simple skip vote.

What I'm trying to achieve is that when 4 members react with the skip reaction `if control == 'skip':` ⏩  it will skip the song.

here is what I'm working with to give you a better look on what I'm trying to do here.

```
async def buttons_controller(self, guild, current, source, channel, context):
    vc = guild.voice_client
    vctwo = context.voice_client

    for react in self.buttons:
        await current.add_reaction(str(react))

    def check(r, u):
        if not current:
            return False
        elif str(r) not in self.buttons.keys():
            return False
        elif u.id == self.bot.user.id or r.message.id != current.id:
            return False
        elif u not in vc.channel.members:
            return False
        elif u.bot:
            return False
        return True

    while current:
        if vc is None:
            return False

        react, user = await self.bot.wait_for('reaction_add', check=check)
        control = self.buttons.get(str(react))

        if control == 'rp':
            if vc.is_paused():
                vc.resume()
            else:
                vc.pause()

        if control == 'skip':
            total_votes = len(control)
            if total_votes >= 3:
                vc.stop()
                await channel.send('Skip vote passed, skipping song...')

        if control == 'stop':
            mods = get(guild.roles, name="Mods")
            for member in list(guild.members):
                if mods in member.roles:
                    await context.invoke(self.bot.get_command("stop"))
                    return
            else:
                await channel.send('Only a mod can stop and clear the queue. Try skipping the song instead.', delete_after=5)

        if control == 'vol_up':
            player = self._cog.get_player(context)
            vctwo.source.volume += 2.5

        if control == 'vol_down':
            player = self._cog.get_player(context)
            vctwo.source.volume -= 2.5

        if control == 'thumbnail':
            await channel.send(embed=discord.Embed(color=0x17FD6E).set_image(url=source.thumbnail).set_footer(text=f"Requested By: {source.requester} | Video Thumbnail: {source.title}", icon_url=source.requester.avatar_url), delete_after=10)

        if control == 'tutorial':
            await channel.send(embed=discord.Embed(color=0x17FD6E).add_field(name="How to use the music controller?", value="⏯ - Pause\n⏭ - Skip\n➕ - Increase Volume\n➖ - Increase Volume\n - Get Thumbnail\n⏹ - Stop & Leave\nℹ - Queue\n❔ - Display help for music controls"), delete_after=10)

        if control == 'queue':
            await self._cog.queue_info(context)

        try:
            await current.remove_reaction(react, user)
        except discord.HTTPException:
            pass
```

I'm looking at this part of the code `if control == 'skip':` which on reaction skips the song playing or if no song is queued stops to song playing.

`vc.stop()` this instructs the player to stop and if another song is queued it will play the next song, otherwise stops if no more songs are queued.

I've tried this function but this is not working for me.

```
if control == 'skip':
        total_votes = len(control)
        if total_votes >= 3:
            vc.stop()
            await channel.send('Skip vote passed, skipping song...')
```

If anyone can tell me where I'm going wrong here I'd appreciated it. An example or some input on this would be greatful.

Comment: `total_votes = len(control)`: Your `if` statement (`if control == 'skip'`) implies that `control` is a string: Therefore, `total_votes` will always be 4 in this block.

Comment: The issue is that when a member skips it's not meeting threshold 4 it'll just skip on 1 reaction.

Comment: Yes, that's because of the comment I made prior. `total_votes` is being set to the length of control, and control is the string `skip`, the length of which is 4.

Comment: Is it possible you could give me an example? I'm not sure how to go about preventing this from happening.

Comment: I don't see your full code, however you need a method that can count the amount of the reaction. It'll likely be `react.count`, but this may depend on the version of discord.py you're using

Comment: That would be this part I think `for react in self.buttons:
            await current.add_reaction(str(react))`

Comment: Look lower than that: `react, user = await self.bot.wait_for('reaction_add', check=check)`. `react` is the object of the reaction. I'll post an answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your check for the total votes is checking the wrong variable and returning a constant value:

```
if control == 'skip':
    total_votes = len(control)
    if total_votes >= 3:
        vc.stop()
        await channel.send('Skip vote passed, skipping song...')
```

`control` is defined inside this `if` as being `'skip'` (because otherwise `control == 'skip'` wouldn't evaluate as true). Therefore, the `len(control)` is 4 (4 characters in the string `'skip'`). To check the actual number of reactions of that type, you need to check the [reaction object](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/rewrite/api.html#discord.Reaction) returned in the following line:

```
react, user = await self.bot.wait_for('reaction_add', check=check)
```

`react` is the reaction object, and the API states it holds the attribute `count` for the amount of times the reaction has been sent. Using this, replace the line `total_votes = len(control)` with `total_votes = react.count` to get the actual number of times the reaction has been sent.